# Docker: Openjdk:14 RHEL based imaged, cannot install yum/wget/netstat

Tags: docker, rhel, redhat-openjdk

In my dockerfile, I need a maven builder (3.6 at least) working on a OpenJDK (J14 is required).

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14 as builder
```

The problem is simple: I need `netstat` command because it is used in several scripts. The OpenJDK official image is RHEL based, so it comes without any of this package installed.
I tried to download it or yum via `wget` command but, as you can guess, it is not installed. I feel trapped because it seems like you cannot you can't install any package on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That image is actually based on Oracle

```
$ podman run -it maven:3.6.3-openjdk-14 /bin/bash -c 'cat /etc/os-release'
NAME="Oracle Linux Server"
VERSION="8.2"
ID="ol"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="8.2"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Oracle Linux Server 8.2"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:oracle:linux:8:2:server"
HOME_URL="https://linux.oracle.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.oracle.com/"

ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux 8"
ORACLE_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.2
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Oracle Linux"
ORACLE_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.2
```

And this is actually a "slim" variant where `dnf` or `yum` aren't installed, but `microdnf` is. Try using that, instead:

```
RUN microdnf install /usr/bin/netstat
```

Or

```
RUN microdnf install net-tools
```